# Expand tab to fit screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I am designing on WinForms; I put organise my dialog boxes according to tabs. However, on certain computers on different resolutions I obtain something like this:

[image]

Where it does not fit the main dialog box exactly. What properties should i set such that it fits the screen totally?

Comment: Anchor all sides or Dock = Fill.

Comment: @LarsTech I have tried to anchor `Top, Bottom, Left, Right` or Dock = Fill, but both does not seem to work. I get back the same output.

Comment: If that's a panel we are looking at, make sure that it is also Dock.Fill.